# Requesting historical diffs of a since moved file from Git

Tags: git, history, renaming

Suppose I had file `X`, which existed for many years and was modified several times. I can see its log and also request diff of any change in the log.

Now, this file was renamed to `Y` (or moved to a different directory) and this change was committed. Output of command `git log Y` shows only entry: the last, renaming commit. However, I can work around this with `--follow` option: `git log --follow Y` will show me the last commit, but additionally all changes that happened to the file while it still had the old name `X`.

However, I don't know how to query Git about *changes* in that file. I can, of course, query change for a commit over the whole repository and then read only that piece of it that is relevant. But is there some option to `git diff` that will do that for me?

*[This is quite important, since the application I work with was switched to using Maven and so practically all source files were moved around, sometimes even more than once.]*

Comment: Have you tried git log -p -- <filename>

Comment: @MudassirRazvi: This is certainly helpful if combined with `--follow`, but I'd still like a way to get a diff separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `--stat` to find out what is the sha-1 of the renamed commit

`git log --follow --stat b.txt`

for example:

```
...
...
53f0655 ggg
a.txt => b.txt | 0
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
69a4b0a ggg
a.txt | 2 +-
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
a67b02d ggg
a.txt | 2 +-
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
b1168f7 ggg
a.txt | 1 +
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

As you can see the last commit is the rename and then use it as your log range:

`git log --follow --stat --oneline 53f0655...HEAD b.txt`

Comment: You can always use `git bisect --run` to find out the commit id if there are too much commits to go over manually

Comment: But the question was how to get a diff of that commit, only for the file in question (for its old name, of course).

Comment: Hi again.
once you have the desired commit (find manually or using git bisect) you can view a specific diff (patch) of this commit `git format-patch -1 <SHA-1>`

Comment: This gives me a diff for all files touched by that commit. I can of course see the relevant bit for the file in question, but is there a way to request diff of only *one* file, if I don't know its old name?